# First letter auto capitalizing of v-text-field in vuejs vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, capitalization

I am trying to captitalize first letter of  v-text-field in vuejs but unbale to do. How to do this?

[image]

first letter should be auto capital when i am input text like in pic.

Comment: If you bind it to a variable you can get that char this way: `firstName[0]` and then modify it your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be to use a [watcher](https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchersfile=/src/layout.vue). This triggers whenever `firstName` is changed.

```js
    <template>
      <v-text-field v-model="firstName" label="First Name"></v-text-field>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          firstName: "",
        };
      },
      methods: {
        capitalizeFirstLetter: (str) => {
          return str ? str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1) : "";
        },
      },
      watch: {
        firstName: function(newValue) {
          this.firstName = this.capitalizeFirstLetter(newValue);
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: I would add a null check to capitalizeFirstLetter, otherwise great solution, worked like charm for me.

Comment: @OverMars good call. Added it

Comment: Looking back at this 2 years later I also changed the access of first letter from .charAt(0) to str[0] because this is wayyy faster

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `v-text-field` supports `v-model` but I would update input when it loses focus.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      text: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    capitalize() {
      const [firstLetter, ...rest] = this.text.split('');
      const upperCaseLetter = firstLetter.toUpperCase();
      
      if (firstLetter === upperCaseLetter) {
        return;
      }

      this.text = firstLetter.toUpperCase() + rest.join('');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="text" type="text" @blur="capitalize" placeholder="Enter text">
</div>
```

Comment: by the way: splitting your string and joining it again like this is awkwardly slow

Comment: OP asked for a potential solution using vue. There are many ways to capitalize string in javascript and every one of them performs differently under specific versioned browser.

Comment: No offense in any way. Your solution definitely works! Was just a hint for optimisation. If you're interesting in checking out the differences in speed (https://jsperf.com/capitalize-string-functions). Just press Run tests at the bottom right to see the two functions compare to eachother. Again, no offense but ~90-95% difference in ops/sec is not to be neglected